# Django 'string_if_invalid' non-default behavior

Tags: python, django, django-templates

In a template, I use certain output formats according to whether a given variable exists (then I edit it in a form) or doesn't exist (then I display a form to create a new value for it), like so:

```
<!-- formatted for readability: -->
<form action="
     {% if instance %}
          {% url 'app:submit_updated_instance' instance.id %}
     {% else %}
          {% url 'app:submit_new_instance' %}
     {% endif %}" 
 method="post"> .... </form>
```

When `instance` doesn't exist, I get long exception traces printed to console by my logger.

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/templates/api/#how-invalid-variables-are-handled), `string_if_invalid`'s default value is `""`, so any exception originating in a template tag should not be printed to logs.

I combed every `string_if_invalid`-related question in SO and none of the answers worked for me.

What could be causing the opposite behavior of the default one in my case, and how do I fix it?

Thanks!

---

Example exception trace:

```
[DEBUG] Exception while resolving variable 'instance' in template 'app/instances_form.html'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/username/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in _resolve_lookup
    (bit, current))  # missing attribute
VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [instance] in u'[{\'False\': False, \'None\': None, \'True\': True}, {u\'csrf_token\'.......  # very long object printed here
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. It doesn’t appear the default value is being set. Error is resolved if I set the key to None.

Comment: Do you send the expected key (e.g. `instance`) with the value `None` from the view, or do you have some way to handle it in the template?